# How to access SampleAppLite.rpd's table in sql developer(toad)?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have SampleApplite.rpd as repository sample from obiee11g, in that repository, there is some table , for example :samp_targets_f.
I want to check data inside those table, so in toad i log in as sys, but i couldn't find tables belong to sampleapplite.rpd
I try it in my localhost for practice, so i open that repository offline.

How to access those table from toad?could i try to log in in other schema?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The table are actually XML files in the BI server file system: BI_EE_HOME/sample/SampleAppFiles/data